# Order mysql query by id but also by extra part

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to order a db table by champion name but using id from another table and if that ID = Champion ID then it will order.

I tried this but it does not order properly it seems to miss place some rows in the order so i think my query is missing something. I have tried with asc and desc and still comes out buggy

```
SELECT Plat_PLUS_Champion_Stats.*
FROM Plat_PLUS_Champion_Stats, Champion_Data
WHERE concat(Plat_PLUS_Champion_Stats.Champ_ID, '.jpg') = 
Champion_Data.Champion_Sub_Background
ORDER BY Champion_Data.Champion
```

The aim would be to get data from this table

Champion_Data Table

```
id    Champion    Champion_Sub_Background        
---|------------|-------------------------|
6  |   Janna    |         80.jpg          |     
5  |   Karthus  |         123.jpg         |      
7  |   Aatrox   |         45.jpg          |   
1  |   Talon    |         95.jpg          |
```

Plat_PLUS_Champion_Stats Table

```
id    Champ_ID           
---|------------|
6  |     80     |     
5  |     45     |     
7  |    123     |  
1  |     95     |
```

The aim is to get the Champ_ID and compare to Champion_Sub_Background if both the same number then to show the Champion ordered desc.

Comment: Do you mean to say it's ordering but in the inverse order that you want it? Change the last line to `ORDER BY Champion_Data.Champion DESC`

Comment: No its ordering but not properly. I have it ordering but its not 100% fully in order no matter with desc, ascor with out

Comment: Hm, where to begin? This is terrible design. If you want to find an image associated with a particular id, search for the id, not the image!

Answer (score 0):

I shortened the table names for clarity.  Using your select, it's difficult to see if the order is correct:

```
select stats.* 
from champion_data as data, plat_plus_champion_stats as stats 
where concat(stats.champ_id, '.jpg')=data.champion_sub_background 
order by data.champion desc 

id  champ_id
1   95
7   123
6   80
5   45
```

So I added in the table with the names:

```
select stats.*, data.* 
from champion_data as data, plat_plus_champion_stats as stats 
where concat(stats.champ_id, '.jpg')=data.champion_sub_background 
order by data.champion desc 

id  champ_id    id  champion   champion_sub_background  
1   95          1   Talon       95.jpg
7   123         5   Karthus     123.jpg
6   80          6   Janna       80.jpg
5   45          7   Aatrox      45.jpg
```

Your query is working fine; it just needs `DESC` in the `ORDER BY`.  Most likely you got confused with the `id` field.  It doesn't match up between the two tables-- notice the difference between id fields for Karthus and Aatrox.  It'd be easy to get confused using them to judge if the order is correct.